# JAXB custom exception marshalling error

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf, jax-ws

I have a library containing beans that are passed between the server and the client application. It also contains a custom exception class:

```
public class MyServiceException extends Exception{
  private int code;
  private String description;

  public MyServiceException(int code, String description){
    super(code + ": " + description);
    this.code = code;
    this.description = description;
  }

  public int getCode() {
    return code;
  }
  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }
}
```

When the server throws the exception, this happens on the client:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Marshalling Error: MyServiceException.<init>(java.lang.String)
..........
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: MyServiceException.<init>(java.lang.String)
```

if I add a no-arg constructor to the exception class it works, but the code and description fields are 0 and null. They are however present in the super class detailsMessage. I don't have this problem with any of the other beans. Implementing Serializable did not help. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that the class was missing setters.